# ATP shared exadata infrastructure OJVM support

Tags: oracle

Looking at the last version of Oracle Autonomous Database shared infrastructure

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsn/index.html

it seems that it now support OJVM.

Is that my understanding correct ?
I can't find any mention about it anywhere else.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. That has been added very recently. And the doc should be enough no? There's a mention of that [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/post/autonomous-database-newsletter---july-28-2022)

Comment: Thank you, it was just to be sure.
In the previous months we evaluated the ADB adoption, but the absence of JVM support was blocking it.
Good news!